# React: How to Add and update Elements into an Array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am sending  a new item to the database and inside that data there is an array with some id. I'm using **node and expressJs**.
**So, the idea is If there is an object exists, I want to update the array inside the object. Or the object will be created in mongodb.**

**The Issue is:** On first submit it adds to the database with an array. But on other clicks the array just got replaced with new Id.

```js
 app.put("/destination", async (req, res) => {
      const email = req.query.email;
      const query = { email: email };
      let result;
      if (query) {
        const cursor = userCarCollection.find(query);
        const userNewIds = req.body;
        result = await collection.updateOne(
          query,
           { $set: userNewIds },
          { upsert: true }
        );
      } else {
        result = await carCollection.insertOne(userNewCar);
      }
      res.send(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution guys. Sorry for any inconvenience. I had to use `$push` method not `$set` method. As, I am a beginner I couldn't think that way.
My solution is as follows and it's working perfectly:

```js
if (query) {
        const cursor = userCarCollection.find(query);
        const userNewIds = req.body.productId.toString();
        result = await userCarCollection.updateOne(
          query,
          {
            $push: {
              productId: userNewIds,
            },
          },
          { upsert: true }
        );
      }
```